# Reasons why Android camera unavailable

Tags: android, camera

I using android `android.hardware.Camera` class to capture image. For initialization I use following code.

```
Camera cam = null;
try {
    cam = Camera.open();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // camera unavailable
}
return cam;
```

I am interesting in `catch` block. For example, torch app is running at the moment of initialization. So `Camera.open()` throw `RuntimeException` with message `Fail to connect to camera service`.
Here is exception:

[image: Fail to connect camera Exception]

Is it possible to know the reason why camera is unavailable? I want to guide user how to fix this, for example show a dialog: "dude, turn off your torch". 
If it's not possible, then in which cases camera could be blocked? I just will show user dialog with general instruction what he could do, for example: 1. turn off torch. 2. Close all camera app 3. Fed your cat etc.

Comment: Not possible - unless you gain extended privileges. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/how-can-i-detect-which-background-application-is-using-the-camera-microphone-or

Comment: Did you add required camera permissions in the manifest?

Comment: @AbdenaceurLichiheb yes

Comment: @MuratK. why you don't write it as an answer? :) this is super related!